# How to send "<" characters to Word documents (.doc, docx) using Sendkeys method

Tags: c#, sendkeys

When i try to send "<" characters it decreasing characters punto only, and doesnt appear "<" char on document.

Could you please help me to solve this problem?

```
SendKeys.SendWait(Convert.ToChar(60).ToString());
```

or

```
SendKeys.SendWait("<");
```

Comment: What does “decreasing characters punto only” mean?

Comment: I mean it decreasing font size.

Comment: try something like this **SendKeys.SendWait("+(,)");**

Comment: I just tried SendKeys.SendWait("+(<)");  but nothing changed.

Comment: @codeninja That will only work with the US keyboard layout, though, right? SendKeys doesn't work with characters IIRC, it basically simulates pressing `Shift+,`, which will not mean `<` on most keyboard layouts.

Comment: Does it absolutely have to be SendKeys? You know that will send the key to whatever currently has focus which might not necessarily be Word, which is also why SendKeys does not work in Debug / Single Step.

Comment: @Luaan, The solution, I have given is working fine on US keyboard layouts. May i know the generic way of sending keys like *<* on different keyboard layouts?

Comment: `SendKeys.SendWait("<");` should work fine - provided that Word currently has cursor focus, which will not be true if you run this from debug mode. I cannot stress that enough. Please specify what exactly you are trying to achieve, I doubt SendKeys is your best option!

Comment: @codeninja `SendKeys` isn't really good enough for that. It's not what it's designed for anyway :) For example, `SendKeys.SendWait("+,")` works fine on US layouts, where you'd press `Shift+,`. On czech layout, `SendKeys.SendWait("<")` works great. On arabic, `SendKeys.SendWait("+ú");` works.

Comment: thanks for the info @Luaan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that the problem about keyboard layout. When i set my keyboard language to English(US) from Windows. SendKeys.SendWait("<"); works fine on Word(doc,docx) documents.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
>SendKeys.SendWait("+,");
```

It works fine on US Keyboard layout. Please consider the other keyboard layout style as well.